# Why second div is slides down?

Tags: html, css

I've got next html/css code:

```css
.first,
.second {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block
}

.first > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"><h1>first div</h1><ul><li>text</li></ul></div>
<div class="second"><h1>second div</h1></div>
```

Why second div is slides down when I put the ul element inside first div?

[JS Bin link](http://jsbin.com/yekesoreti/1/edit?html,css,output), just in case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the default value of `vertical-align`(applies to inline-level and table-cell elements) is `baseline`, you need to use `vertical-align: top`.

```css
.first,
.second {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.first > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <h1>first div</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <h1>second div</h1>
</div>
```